# replicate-ignore-table setup and usage for excluding table from binlog backup

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, configuration, binlog

I need to make an everyday backup of a mysql database that is very big on a remote server and I only want to get the difference since the last backup. I also need to exclude some tables from being backed up.
I've setup the mysql server as a master, here is the important part of my.cnf i've changed :

`log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_do_db            = my_database`

Then on the backup server i've setup mysql my.cnf like this :

`replicate-ignore-table  = my_db_name.my_table_name`

To test that everything is ok, I do the following:

On Master:

`$ mysql -u root -p
MariaDB [my_database]> insert into my_table (param1, param2, ...) values(1, 1, ...)
MariaDB [my_database]> exit
$ scp /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.00000X vagrant@backupserver:/tmp/`

On Slave:

`$ mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.00000X | mysql -u root -p`

When I check the slave database I always see the new entry in the table, but that's not the expected result....

I must miss something, any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replicate-ignore-table` filter applies only the streaming over replication protocol (specifically in this case the *SQL thread Slave*), it doesn't affect if you apply log changes manually as you are doing. The detailed information about [replication filtering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules.html) can be complemented with the [replication rule application](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules-examples.html) if you want to understand fully the mechanisms for replication filtering.

A very easy [step-by-step tutorial](https://fromdual.com/how_to_setup_mysql_master-slave_replication) will allow you to setup a standard replica using no other tools than the ones included in the official distribution.

Although you don't want to replicate the table, I recommend you to create the table structure but using BLACKHOLE engine for avoiding some scenarios issues.

Comment: After adding this filter replicate-ignore-table='dbname.tablename' binlog size is continuously increasing whenever I update or insert the data in  the ignore table.